# How to conditionally render an element, based on what radio button is checked with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a form built with bootstrap-vue, the radio button code looks something like this:

```
    <b-form-group label="Claim Type">
         <b-form-radio-group
              id="claimType"
              required
              v-model="form.claimType"
              :options="claimTypeOptions"
              name="claimType"
              stacked>
         </b-form-radio-group>
    </b-form-group>
```

And my script looks something like this:

```
     data() {
      return {
      form: {
       claimType: ""
      },
       claimTypeOptions: [
         { text: "Option 1", value: "Option 1" },
         { text: "Option 2", value: "Option 2" }
       ]
  }
```

When I select option 1, I want to use v-if to render a block or hide the block if the other radio button is selected. but how do I reference the state of the radio buttons in my v-if directive correctly? Or is there a better/simpler approach for this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your code, but, to answer your question`v-if="form.claimType === 'Option 1'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your v-model as the statement to check.
Ex.

```
<div v-if="form.claimType === 'Option 1'">
    <span>Show me </span>
</div>
```